# No puedo actualizar los cambios en mi repositorio clonado de git

Tags: github

No entiendo mucho de git, pero clone un repositorio que tenia, le hice algunos cambios en el codigo y quise actualizarlo pero no pude.
Utilice:
1- git add *
2- git commit -m ""
3- git push origin master

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tenés hecho el remoto? El mensaje de error quiere decir que estás tratando de hacer push desde una rama local que no tiene remoto.

Comment: pense que si, perdon por la ignorancia pero no entiendo mucho, ejecute el comando "git remote" y me salio "origin"

Comment: Entonces hay remoto. Fijate que en la imagen tu último comando fue `git push`. Probá con `git push origin master` como habías hecho antes.

Comment: no me deja, al ejecutar ese comando dice "error: failed to push some refs to <url del repositorio>"

Comment: hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

Answer (score 0):

ya lo solocioné usando el comando

```
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: Aunque es una solución, la consola sugiere que tenías que descargar cambios del repositorio remoto y no forzar la carga de los tuyos como sugiere la otra respuesta. Si no sabes inglés, puedes usar un traductor para entender lo que los errores te quieren decir.

Answer (score 0):

La consola te dice que debes hacer pull antes. Puedes hacerlo con:

```
git pull
```